# Cannot figure out role-based pricing rule for custom Product Display/Variation in Commerce Kickstart

Tags: commerce, rules, users

After working thru the Commerce tutorial and understanding roles, I thought it would be straightforward to set up a pricing rule based on user role, but I cannot seem to build the correct "Action" in Rules.

I want to reference a "Dealer Price" field in a Product Variation is the User Role = "dealer"

Error: Data selector *commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field-dealer-price:amount* for parameter *amount* is invalid.

Here are the steps I took to get to my current spot:

1. In a custom Product Variation "Bikes", I created a new field "Dealer Price" that mirrors the "Price" field that is already part of Commerce Kickstart
   Dealer price
   Field Type: Price
   Widget: Price with Currency
   2, Created role "Dealer"
2. Initiated creation of pricing rule
   Store Settings >> Pricing Rules
   Add Pricing Rule
   Add Event: Calculating the sell price of a product
   Add Conditions: 1. User has role(s): Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles: dealer; 2. Entity has field: Parameter: Entity: [commerce-line-item], Field: commerce_product; 3. Entity has field: Parameter: Entity: [commerce-line-item], Field: field_dealer_price
3. Then, I get stuck with Add Actions:
4. Select action to add: Commerce Line Item: Set item to specific amount
5. Line Item: Data Selector: commerce_line_item (Already inserted)
6. Amount: [Click on Switch to Data Selector]: commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field-dealer-price:amount
   **or** commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field_dealer_price:amount **or** commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field-dealer_price:amount

I get an error msg when trying to reference the new price field "Dealer Price".

I feel like I am missing a connection within Commerce that ties the Product Variation to the *commerce_line_item*, but I haven't been able to identify the missing link. My products show up correctly in the shopping cart, so that hasn't been an issue.

Any help in tying the concepts of "Roles", "Rules", and "Commerce Kickstart" together is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 3. Entity has field: Parameter: Entity: [commerce-line-item], Field: field_dealer_price

Your price field won't be on `commerce-line-item`. It will be on `commerce-line-item:commerce-product`. You need to check for it there.

> 6. Amount: [Click on Switch to Data Selector]: commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field-dealer-price:amount or commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field_dealer_price:amount or commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field-dealer_price:amount

So since the `field_dealer_price` is on the product instance, you'd be looking at this: `commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field-dealer-price:amount`

An example, without the role condition, would look like this:

```
{ "pricing_from_another_field_example" : {
    "LABEL" : "Role based pricing example",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "commerce_line_item", "commerce_product_reference" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_product_calculate_sell_price" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item" ], "field" : "commerce_product" } },
      { "entity_has_field" : {
          "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-product" ],
          "field" : "field_dealer_price"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_line_item_unit_price_amount" : {
          "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
          "amount" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-product:field-dealer-price:amount" ],
          "component_name" : "base_price",
          "round_mode" : "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this. I am missing something that is probably very obvious. In the "Fields search" report, I confirmed where the standard Drupal Commerce "commerce_price" field and my new "field_dealer_price" is used. Right now, they are used only on the new Product Variations that I created: Bikes, Hubs, etc.

Comment: **Correction** I changed my third condition to "Entity has field" Parameter: `Entity[commerce-line-item:commerce-product,Field: field_dealer_price`. I had mistakenly deleted a condition in my zeal to fix things....Now everything works :) Holy cow! Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! Please be sure to mark your question as answered.